# dividing number without rounding it up and without decimal

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to divide input number and show the result without decimals and without rounding it up, so if I divide 80/50 I want to get 1, not 2 (1.6).

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim box1 As Decimal = TextBox1.Text()
        TextBox6.Text = box1 / 50
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Incidentally, you really should set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project and as the default for new projects. It will let Visual Studio point out problems in your code for you, and even offer possible fixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Truncate` Method of `Decimal`:

```
Dim result As Decimal = Decimal.Truncate(CDec(80 / 50))
Console.WriteLine("result : " & result.ToString)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\` operator to do integer division.

```
Dim result = 80 \ 50 'result is Integer with value 1
```